# What is the output in Figure 3-19(a) if the input voltage is increased to a peak value of 20 v?

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes, zener, output

Will it be the same as if the input voltage is still 10 V? Or the zener diodes will breakdown (get damaged)?
[image]

Comment: You can embed pictures rather than links. Consider doing this. Also, you need to show some attempt at figuring this out yourself because it looks like homework.

Comment: @Andy aka  Both are images but they're more than the allowed 2MB. And this a related problem to a given example in The reference "Electronic Devices" for Floyd, not a homework.

Comment: OK, so get hold of a free simulation tool and simulate it. I can recommend micro-cap student edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The peaks will increase because real zeners are not "ideal" and have an internal resistance that causes a greater volt drop when conducting more current (due to the increased input voltage).

The slopes will approximately double because the input waveform has doubled in magnitude.

> Or the zener diodes will breakdown (get damaged)?

An unfortunate choice of words - a zener is said to breakdown when the reverse voltage exceeds the "breakdown" voltage. It doesn't mean it will break-down (like a car) and there isn't enough information in the question to ascertain if either zener will fail when the input voltage doubles.

Comment: The internal resistance of the Zener diode is negligible compared to 1k resistance.  But if we take such details into account, then let's show it on the horizontal part of the waveform.  Also, the ends will be rounded because of the horizontal initial part of the diode IV curve. I do not think this is appropriate at this initial stage where the idea is to get a notion about the behavior of an "ideal" Zener diode (VZ when backward connected, VF when forward connected). Details are for the next stage. Don't get me wrong; I say it as a teacher...